# Comparing rates of change: which function increases faster?

Tags: functions, derivatives, logarithms, factorial

I am comparing two functions for $x \ge 1$:

$$f(x) = \ln(\lfloor\frac{x}{9}\rfloor!) - \ln(\lfloor\frac{x}{10}\rfloor!) - \ln(\lfloor\frac{x}{90}\rfloor!)$$

$$g(x) = (2.07766)\sqrt{\frac{x}{9}} + (0.057712778)x$$

Comparing their values over a finite range suggests that $f(x)$ grows slightly faster than $g(x)$.

Since $f(x)$ is not continuous, I am not able to use its derivative to establish the rate of growth.  How can I verify that as $x$ increases, $f(x)$ increases faster than $g(x)$?

Thanks,

-Larry

---

**Edit:** It looks like I copied the problem wrong.  It should have read $(0.057712778)x$ instead of $(0.103883)x$.  The correct term was $(1.03883)*\frac{x}{18} = (0.057712778)x$.

Comment: The change has decreased $g(x)$, so the prior argument is even more valid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is a bit messy since $f(x)$ is a step function.  Initially, we can remove the steps with the restriction $x=90y$, under which conditions $f(y)=\ln (10y)! - \ln (9y)! - \ln (y)!$.  We can now use [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) to get $f(y)=10y\ln (10y)-10y -9y\ln (9y) +9y -y\ln y + y + O(\ln (10y)) = 10y \ln 10 + 10y \ln y -9y \ln 9 - 9y \ln y - y \ln y + O(\ln (10y)) = y(10 \ln 10 - 9 \ln 9) + O(\ln (10y))\approx 3.250829733 y + O(\ln (10y))$.

On the other hand, $g(y)=(2.07766)\sqrt{10}\sqrt{y}+(0.103883)(90y)=9.34947y+O(\sqrt{y})$.

Based on this, for at least those $x$ that are multiples of $90$, we can say that $g(x)$ grows faster than $f(x)$ (eventually), although they are both close to linear growth.

Comment: When $x$ is large, the floors don't matter and this is a good argument without worrying about that.

Comment: Thanks, Vadim123.  I appreciate you your reasoning!  :-)  Would you have any thoughts on the exact $x$ where $g(x)$ starts to grow faster than $f(x)$?

Comment: My computations suggest that $g(y)>f(y)$ for all $y$, starting with $y=1$.  However, for such small $y$, the floors *do* matter.

Comment: Hi @vadim123, it looks like I copied the problem wrong.  I've updated the formula from $(0.103883)x$ to $(0.057712778)x$.  To be clear, when I check this formula, for any change in $x$ that I try, $f(x)$ increases faster than $g(x)$ even as $g(x) > f(x)$.  For example, from $x=900$ to $x=1000$, $f(x)$ changes as a percentage by $1.1085 31752$ while $g(x)$ changes as a percentage by $1.094820095$.  If even with my correction, $g(x)$ increases faster, at what $x$ does it start increasing faster?  Thanks.

Comment: This changes 9.34947 to 5.19415, but the conclusion remains the same.